# Requisição Ajax jquery Jsonp Retornando Undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, undefined, requisição

Preciso fazer o tratamento do retorno das informações do seguinte código abaixo. Lembrando que ele funciona corretamente porém, em algum momento, o termo buscado não existe retornando "undefined" e não mostra nada na tela. Preciso que neste momento busque uma imagem padrão guardada localmente.
Agradeço desde já.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({  
type: "GET",
url: "http://alvoparabusca.com.br", 
data: {termo:"termo da busca",limitado:1,tipo:"imagem"},

success: function(data){
    img = data["resultado"][0].imagem;
    $("html").css({"background-image":"url("+ img +")"});
},
dataType: "jsonp"
});

</script>
```

Comment: se você dá um console.log em `data` qual o resultado?

Comment: Quando retorna Undefined o Console retorna: Object {resultCount: 0, results: Array[0]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data && data.resultCount > 0) {
    img = data["resultado"][0].imagem;
    $("html").css({
      "background-image": "url(" + img + ")"
    });
  } else { //Se não for localizado, seta sua imagem default
    $("html").css({
      "background-image": "url(suaImagemDefault.jpg)"
    });
  }
}
```

seria isso ?

Comment: É essa a ideia Brunno, Mas não funcionou aqui, quando não existe a imagem está dando o mesmo problema dentro do if. Tentei trocar para if (data === 'undefined') desta forma ele passa para o else e fica lá, mesmo existindo a imagem.

Comment: @Emetec, tente o if de acordo com o edit que fiz na resposta

Comment: Nada ainda @Brunno. Toda vez que entra no if para comparar ele encerra indicando que "imagem" é "undefined" não executa o else. Estou tentando validar antes do sucess. Se existir valor executa o sucess caso contrário vai para error.

Comment: @Emetec, amigo, se você adicionar um console.log(data); antes do if, o que ele imprime no console do seu brownser ? undefined, 'undefined', null ?

Comment: Mostra o seguinte @Brunno: Object {resultCount: 0, results: Array[0]} e logo abaixo: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagem' of undefined

Comment: @Emetec, de acordo com o seu retorno parece que o resultCount seta a quantidade de resultado então basta mudar o if para: if (data && data.resultCount > 0) editei a resposta. Teste ai :)

Comment: Perfeito @Brunno. Agora funcionou corretamente. Muito obrigado.